# What is the word most commonly used for the the sound of glass breaking? (Onomatopoeia)

Tags: onomatopoeia

Please provide me with the word most commonly used for the the sound of glass breaking. (Onomatopoeia)

Comment: Do you mean the "noise made by breaking glass"?

Comment: @Peter Shor Good question. The noise made by stepping on broken glass is very unique as well.

Comment: @tkendrick20 It is? Really? How unique is it?

Answer (score 3):

- [**crack**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Crack)

<sup>v.intr.3.</sup> To break without complete separation of parts; fissure: *The mirror cracked.*

<sup>v.tr.2.</sup> To cause to break without complete separation of parts: *cracked the glass*

- [**smash**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/smash) <sup>v.intr.1.</sup>To break (something) into pieces suddenly, **noisily**, and violently;
- [**shattered**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shattered)  is to break into many scattered pieces: *The coffin fell to the floor, the glass was shattered to bits by the concussion*

Comment: But do those terms describe the *noise* as per the question?

Comment: @TrevorD If you look at the OP's title it's a fair bet he/she is not a native speaker, hence it's pretty fair to assume that what is being asked is the onomatopoeic words related to broken glass. onomatopoeic not being in everyone's vocabulary, especially non-natives speakers (unless they speak the Romance languages of course!).

Comment: I did actually think of that, and looked at the definitions you quote before commenting. The definitions all relate to the *action* of breaking, and, although they are sometimes used to *describe* the sound, I don't think of them as "words whose sounds imitate the sound or action they represent, eg *boo*, *hiss*, *squelch*." ([Chambers](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=onomatopoeic&title=21st) def. of *onomatopoeic*). But maybe I'm wrong? :-(

Comment: @Mari-LouA, the answer should be structured after the question even if there's a chance the OP used a word wrong. Not only because one shouldn't incorrectly answer a question based on the chance the question was incorrectly asked, but also because the question and answer to it will actually be used by other people too. Also, incorrectly answering the question doesn't really improve the English capabilities of the OP, and if there is any ambiguity to their own understanding of the question they asked, then a questioning comment is better than a wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no specific word for that. The following sounds more or less the same.

Clink - Small bits of glass knocking together &
Smash - Break violently into small pieces.